# Emacs Lisp: make newly-created buffer visible before the function returns?

Tags: emacs, lisp, buffer, visibility

In the following function in emacs Lisp,

```
(defun show-life ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer "*Life-Window*") ; show how life goes on while living
  (live)) ; it takes 70 years to finish and return!
```

I'd like to create the buffer "*Life-Window*", and have the life event generated by (live) displayed continuously while live goes on.

Unfortunately, the buffer only becomes visible after the (live) returns (when it's over!)

I also tried pop-to-buffer, the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a call to `'sit-for` just before the call to `'live`, e.g.

```
(defun show-life ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer "*Life-Window*")    ; show how life goes on while living
  (sit-for 0)                           ; perform redisplay
  (live))                               ; it takes 70 years to finish and return!
```

And, if you want to see the results of `'live`, it should periodically call `'sit-for` as well.

The doc string for `'sit-for` is:

> sit-for is a compiled Lisp function in
>   `subr.el'. (sit-for seconds &optional
>   nodisp)
>
> Perform redisplay, then wait for
>   seconds seconds or until input is
>   available. seconds may be a
>   floating-point value. (On operating
>   systems that do not support waiting
>   for fractions of a second,
>   floating-point values are rounded down
>   to the nearest integer.)
>
> If optional arg nodisp is t, don't
>   redisplay, just wait for input.
>   Redisplay does not happen if input is
>   available before it starts.
>
> Value is t if waited the full time
>   with no input arriving, and nil
>   otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I found out the solution. I have to use `(sit-for <time-to-wait>)` to get the buffer to show the update of life events.

So the code segment should be modified as follows:

```
(defun show-life ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer "*Life-Window*") ; show how life goes on while living
  (sit-for 0)
  (live)) ; it takes 70 years to finish and return!
```

Maybe inside of the `live` body, `sit-for` should be called periodically.

Comment: We were channeling the same vibe, down to the word "periodically".